# Matching regex pattern that contains .* in Spring

Tags: regex, spring, mongodb

I'm trying to match a pattern in Spring using Criteria, like below:

```
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("regex").regex("FILENAME_JUNE_EOD_.CSV", "i"));
    mongoTemplate.findOne(query);
```

There's a field in the collection fr each object called 'regex' which contains a regex pattern that is to be matched with the name of the file. The regex in question is:

```
    .*[\\\\/]FILENAME_.*_EOD_.*[.]CSV
```

This doesn't seem to match. What's strange is that it matches when I change the name of the file to just 'FILENAME_', so it seems like the .* part of the regex is what is causing issues. Is this something to do with Spring not being able to handle standard mongo regex syntax?

Comment: Typo, now corrected

Comment: In the character class `[\\\\/]` you are matching a forward slash or a backslash but there is none of them. Try `.*FILENAME_.*_EOD_.*[.]CSV`

Comment: The backslashes don't seem to make any difference in matching this pattern. I've tried removing them and I still get the exact same issue.

Comment: OK I think I know the issue. The regex that Spring checks against can't be within the mongo object. I reversed the position of the parameters and it matches correctly now. However this is still problematic since the regex to be matched is contained within the database, it's not going to be sent as a parameter (which is how the file name is currently being sent).